# ng-if animation angularjs collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've got a little issue using the animation in angularjs. I can expand and collapse a div but when i collapse it the content of the div disappear after the container collapse. It should be collapse together instead.. I made a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7tb4g/119/

the css is very simple:

```
.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear all;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear all;
    -o-transition: 1s linear all;
    transition: 1s linear all;
}

 .animate-if.ng-enter {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

 .animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    max-height: 999px;
    opacity:1;
}

 .animate-if.ng-leave {
    max-height: 999px;
    opacity:1;
}

 .animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity:1;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple fix with `overflow:hidden;`

```
.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear all;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear all;
    -o-transition: 1s linear all;
    transition: 1s linear all;
    /* no overflow during animation */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7tb4g/121/)**</kbd>